# Why is writer of os/exec.StderrPipe closed in Start()?

Tags: go

Can someone help me understand why [`pw` (the writer)](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.11/src/os/exec/exec.go#L614) is scheduled for closing in [Start()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.11/src/os/exec/exec.go#L395)?

I would expect `pw` to be closed together with [`pr` ( the reader)](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.11/src/os/exec/exec.go#L615) in [Wait()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.11/src/os/exec/exec.go#L478).

Comment: Question applies to StderrPipe and StdoutPipe.

Comment: I think `pw` is scheduled for closing in start due to this reason in the   "The pipe will be closed automatically after Wait sees the command exit.A caller need only call Close to force the pipe to close sooner.  
For example, if the command being run will not exit until standard input
is closed, the caller must close the pipe.".

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/41e62b8c49d21659b48a95216e3062032285250f/src/os/exec/exec.go#L529

Answer (score 0):

`closeAfterStart` and `closeAfterwait` are two slices of `io.Closers` which are called respectively ins `Start` and `Wait` of `cmd` Struct. Now, why is this? both these are basically  buffers(slices) which either need to be written into read off of. Depending on whether they are currently in use, they are closed. for example `StdInPipe` requires reading first and then writing to, therefore the `pr` is included in `closeAfterStart` and `pw` in `closeAfterWait`. The reverse is done for `StdOutPipe`.

The program is simply closing off the buffers which it doesn't need anymore in the code. In `StdErrPipe` the function is called after execution of command, to write the error output to some output. So, the program already has the output it needs to write.